# Is date +%s result in local time zone or in UTC?

Tags: date, unix, timestamp, utc

When I type `date +%s` into a terminal, is the resulting timestamp given in `UTC` or is it dependent on my system locale setting?  Is there a way to check?

Is there a standard for this across OS's?

Comment: Your system locale setting affects things like how dates are displayed ("Mar 9, 2015" vs. "2015-03-09"). The time zone setting is distinct from that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `man date`:

> **%s**     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC**

So it is UTC.